# Running eclipse with command line arguments

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there some way by which I can configure eclipse to run a program with certain command line arguments for debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to configure the command line arguments for Eclipse: Under Run configurations>Arguments

Read [here](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html)

Also consider using Ant as a build script. Works better in the long run.

Comment: +1 for the Ant suggestion. Eclipse behaves strangely at times with the command line arguments.